# Расположить элементы не по порядку в шаблоне на Flex

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как можно расположить контейнеры не по порятку 1 2 3, а как 1 3 2 на ccs flex, не нашел как там задаваить порядок.

```
.school-board {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main-tx {
  height: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

<div class="school-board">
<div class="main-tx">1</div>
<div class="main-tx">2</div>
<div class="main-tx">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.school-board {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main-tx {
  height: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

.school-board div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="school-board">
<div class="main-tx">1</div>
<div class="main-tx">2</div>
<div class="main-tx">3</div>
</div>
```

`.item { order: <любое целое число>; /* дефолтное 0 */ }`

Comment: так еще проще, поправил

Comment: непонимаю почему если задать второму блоку порядок один то он оказываеться внизу, почему так происходит?

Comment: по умолчанию:`.school-board div:nth-child(1) {order: 0;}` `.school-board div:nth-child(2) {order: 0;}` `.school-board div:nth-child(3) {order: 0;}` меняя у 2 блока позицию на 1, я его смещаю в самый низ